# How to show hide dynamically in angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

```
>on click an English button it shows its corresponding div at the same time if I clicked on another button then it shows its div but the previous one not closed. I want that on click English it shows the div and on again click it close.
>Note that makes it dynamically because I don't know how many lang are there.
>make sure you don't make it for static data.
```

## ***in my HTML ***

```
 <div *ngFor="let lang of langList;let index = index" >
          <div class="engbutton">
              <button class="englishButton" (click)="onclickEnglishDiv(lang,index)">{{ lang }}</button>
              <div *ngIf="visibleIndex === index" class="knowEnglish">
                <div>
                  <div *ngFor="let data of filteredLangList" class="engDivObj">{{data.name}}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

***in my TS***

```
 onclickEnglishDiv(clickLang,index){  
    if (this.visibleIndex !== index) {
      this.visibleIndex = index;
    }     
  }
```

- on click any div it open that  .but on click next one it opens the next one as well as it closes the first one.
  *** What I want ***

```
I want that on click first button it opens its div, 
on click second button it opens its div .but, doesn't close the first one. The first one is closed when the first button only clicked.
- make it dynamically like when new data come it works with the flow.
```

here is my sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-showhide-088?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsho-hide%2Fsho-hide.component.html

here you can find it jquery version:https://www.bootply.com/90JfjI2Q7n
the above functionality I need in angular 7. with dynamic type, not hardcore 
type like define boolean value for every div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution might be to store not a visible index, but visible indices, like:

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="container">
      <div *ngFor="let lang of langList;let index = index" >
          <div class="engbutton">
              <button class="englishButton" (click)="onclickEnglishDiv(lang, index)">{{ lang }}</button>
              <div *ngIf="visibleIndices.has(index)" class="knowEnglish">
                <div>
                  <div *ngFor="let data of studentList | filterLanguages:lang" class="engDivObj">{{data.name}}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
...
export class ShoHideComponent implements OnInit {
  visibleIndices = new Set<number>();

  ...

  onclickEnglishDiv(clickLang, index): void {
    if (!this.visibleIndices.delete(index)) {
      this.visibleIndices.add(index);
    }
  }
}
```

You may also notice that I moved languages filter logic into `filterLanguages` [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes), because each element should have its own copy of the filtered languages, otherwise all elements would display the same items. [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-showhide-088-kytaow)

---

Another solution might be to create a separate component for the button, like:

```html
<!-- sho-hide.component.html -->
<div class="box">
  <div class="container">
      <div *ngFor="let lang of langList;let index = index" >
          <app-lng-button [lang]="lang" [languages]="studentList | filterLanguages:lang"></app-lng-button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
// lng-button.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lng-button',
  templateUrl: './lng-button.component.html'
})
export class LngButtonComponent {
  @Input()
  lang!: string;

  @Input()
  languages: string[] = []

  open = false;
}
```

```html
<!-- lng-button.component.html -->
<div class="engbutton">
  <button class="englishButton" (click)="open = !open">{{ lang }}</button>
  <div *ngIf="open" class="knowEnglish">
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="let data of languages" class="engDivObj">{{data.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-showhide-088-grx4g7)